# R return dataframe from vector of dataframe names

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, radix

I have a vector (test_vector), and it contains a string; that string is also the name of a dataframe.  I need a function that will allow me to display the dataframe knowing given a value in test-vector:

```
test_vector = "x"
x = tibble(y=seq(1,5))
testdata[1]
```

What I want is an function that wraps around testdata[1] and returns the dataframe x, not the "x" value of  test_vector[1]

Does such a function exist in R.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `get` to return the value of the object

```
get(test_vector[1])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 1
#      y
#  <int>
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     5
```

---

Or another option is to directly checking the `.GlobalEnv`

```
.GlobalEnv[[test_vector[1]]]
```